# How did Chinese triads with the slogan "oppose the Qing, restore the Ming" adapt ideologically to the fall of the Qing and the rise of republicanism?

Tags: china

Clearly triads didn't disappear, but how did they react to this part of their raison raison d'être slipping away?

Edit: I went through the first five links searching this on google and couldn't find an answer. My question asks how they adapted ideologically. The only thing I could find was the Yellow Sands apparently just plowing on through keeping it as their slogan, with no clear explanation as to why.

Comment: What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. Can you explain why the relevant Wikipedia pages and google searches didn't answer the question?  [SE sites work best if the questions are supported by preliminary research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/2085030)

Comment: I wouldn't even know how to search for this other than buying books on the history of Chinese organised crime, or perhaps contacting academics.

Comment: When I search Google for `“oppose the Qing, restore the Ming” triad` I get several sites that appear (to me at least) to answer your question.  Can you edit your question to explain why they don't?

Comment: Did they using their traditions of secrecy and violence metamorph into criminal organisations, if they were not already? Ar you confusing them with 'tongs'?See Wikipedia articles on triads and tongs

Comment: Ok, well, I went through the first five links and couldn't find an answer.
My question asks how they adapted ideologically. The only thing I could find was the Yellow Sands apparently just plowing on through keeping it as their slogan, with no clear explanation as to why.

Comment: Please document your research in your question rather than in comments. Your question will be better received by the community this way (i.e. your questions will probably get upvotes rather than comments asking you what research you have done).

Comment: The order in which the pages are returned is likely to vary depending on a variety of factors.  The first paper for me was [Patriotic Chinese Ttiads and secret societies](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03068374.2019.1636515). In short, “_oppose the Qing, restore the Ming_” was never their _raison d'être_.  At most it was a rallying cry and a part of their foundation myths.

Comment: Well how did it work exactly having their rallying cry and part of their foundation myths become apparently inapplicable to the time they found themselves in? How did they deal with that? If they didn't need to, why not?
I didn't say it was their raison d'être; I said it was part of their raison d'être.

Comment: @StepStart Please read the paper and edit your question to explain what you think is missing from, or incomplete about, their analysis and explanation.

Comment: For non specialists, a date would help.